# R Shiny split lines of text output from renderText()

Tags: r, shiny

I am making a shiny app, and in the app one feature is to output text that is generated as a list of character strings.

For example, one function outputs a list of text, for example

("a", "b", "c", "d")

When I render this text, it outputs it as such

a b c d

Instead I would like the text to be rendered so that there is a line in between each value of the list, so instead it would look like

a

b

c

d

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    htmlOutput("mytext")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytext <- renderUI({
        mylist <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
        HTML(paste(mylist, sep = "", collapse = '<br/>'))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @AndS. answer, another option would be using `renderText()` with `htmlOutput()`, and then simply `paste(mylist, collapse = "<br>")`